# How to calculate fold change of groups?

Tags: r

I have the data frame and want to calculate the fold changes based on the average of two groups, for example:df1

```
value group
  5     A
  2     B
  4     A
  4     B
  3     A
  6     A
  7     B
  8     A
```

The average of group A is (5+4+3+6+8)/5 = 5.2; and the average of group B is (2+4+7)/3 =4.3. The expected result should be 5.2/4.3=1.2.

How can I realize my purpose?

Comment: Please post your desired result

Comment: The expected result should be 2 based on the formula.

Comment: The result of the formula you posted is 1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed you have a dataframe with 3 values like this:

```
df=data.frame(group=rep(c("A","B"),5),
              value1=1:10,value2=21:30,value3=41:50,stringsAsFactors = F)
> df
   group value1 value2 value3
1      A      1     21     41
2      B      2     22     42
3      A      3     23     43
4      B      4     24     44
5      A      5     25     45
6      B      6     26     46
7      A      7     27     47
8      B      8     28     48
9      A      9     29     49
10     B     10     30     50
```

you should use s`tringsAsFactors = F` to create or read your data. then you could calculate fold change with the following codes:

```
res=aggregate(.~group,df,mean)
res["fc",]=c("A.vs.B",as.numeric(res[1,-1])/as.numeric(res[2,-1]))

    group            value1            value2            value3
1       A                 5                25                45
2       B                 6                26                46
fc   A.vs.B             0.83             0.961             0.9782
```

my advise: use package `limma` to calculate fold change and statistical analysis for large scale data.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your expected is you could use the function (either `sum` or `mean`)

We can use `tapply`

```
x <- tapply(df$value, df$group, mean)
x[1]/x[2]
# A 
#1.2
```

Or

```
x <- tapply(df$value, df$group, sum)
x[1]/x[2]
#A 
#2
```

---

We can also use the same thing with `split` and `sapply` by same logic

```
x <- sapply(split(df$value, df$group), mean)
x[1]/x[2]

x <- sapply(split(df$value, df$group), sum)
x[1]/x[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse` methods

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise(value = mean(value)) %>%
    summarise(value = first(value)/last(value))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  value
#  <dbl>
#1   1.2
```

---

Or using `by` from `base R`

```
by(df[,'value'], df['group'], mean)
by(df[,'value'], df['group'], sum)
```

#### data

```
df <-structure(list(value = c(5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L), group = c("A", 
"B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest way is to use `tapply` like in @Ronak's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124413/how-to-calculate-fold-change-of-groups/57125728#57125728) but then perform the division with `Reduce`.

```
tapply(df1$value, df1$group, sum)
# A  B 
#26 13 

Reduce(`/`, tapply(df1$value, df1$group, sum))
#[1] 2
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
value group
  5     A
  2     B
  4     A
  4     B
  3     A
  6     A
  7     B
  8     A
", header = TRUE)
```